# Creating one -> many relationships for a shopping list application swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, relationships

I have the following relationship [image]

The idea is that one "List" entity will have access to many "ItemList" entities i.e. a list will have multiple items on it. I have attempted to add an item to a list entity in the following way:

```
    let newList = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("List", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! List
    newList.name = listName
    newList.shoppingDate = shoppingTripDate
    newList.eventDate = eventDate

    let itemEnt = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("ItemList", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! ItemList
    itemEnt.item = "Eggs"
    itemEnt.list = newList
```

With the line `ItemEnt.list = newList` connecting the two, as you can see with the above screenshot.

However, in another view controller where I retrieve this object from core data and try to access its `item` property like so:

```
shoppingListObject!.itemList!.item
```

This crashes the program.

Am I missing anything or doing something wrong?

edit:
This is the error it produces in the terminal

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_NSFaultingMutableSet item]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd0a4951960'

Comment: Looks fine for me. Can you show more code of that another view controller?

Comment: What error(s) do you get when the app crashes? There are an infinite number of things that can cause crashes, and the error(s) will narrow this down and often point directly to the problem.

Comment: I wonder that this compiles at all. `itemList` should be a *set* for a to-many relationship.

Comment: I think @MartinR is right. @MattSpoon: does this help? `let listItems = shoppingListObject!.itemList!.allObjects as! [ItemList]`

Answer (score 1):

That error is telling you that `itemList` is an `NSSet`. Which makes sense, since that's how Core Data's to-many relationships work. It's also telling you that `NSSet` doesn't have a method named `item`, which also makes sense. You tried to call a method on an `NSSet` that `NSSet` doesn't have, which is why the app crashed.

From your model diagram, `shoppingListObject!.itemList!` is an `NSSet` of instances of `ItemList`. You can access individual instances using `NSSet` methods.

But I agree with Martin's comment-- it's strange that you're able to compile this code. Swift should catch that, unless you're doing something unusual that prevents it from doing so.